# Terminate a UIView transition animation

Tags: objective-c

I am slowly animating a UIImageView from one image to another. Like so:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.backgroundView duration:30 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    self.backgroundView.image = endImage;
} completion:nil];
```

Is there some way to terminate the animation partway through, in response to an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A certain [Tim Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/599344/tim) tells me this is how you do it:

```
[self.backgroundView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

You can also retrieve the frame the animation ended on using `self.layer.presentationLayer.frame`, if you need to freeze the view in the partially animated state.

Comment: Does this definitely work with [UIView transitionWithView] (rather than just with [UIView animateWith...]?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will - try it and let me know. :)

Comment: Aha. Yes, it does. I was initially thrown because my completion block (omitted in the question) loops the animation. Just realised that [view.layer removeAllAnimations] jumps to the completion block. Cheers Sirs Sam and Tim.